# Project based authorization configure Build execute shell

Tags: jenkins

In one of the jobs in jenkins, I as the adminstrator have enabled project based security and added few names who could configure this job.

However, I want to let these people configure only the Execute Shell under Build and the rest of it should be blocked for them.

Unfortunately, the configure flag ( check box ) under Project Based Security opens up the complete job for these people for the configuration.

Is there a way, I can allow users of this job to edit "only" the execute shell under Build and the rest of the configuration remains blocked from them?

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the answer myself. One can uncheck the Configure check box and the contents of the Execute shell can be replaced by a one liner or whatever script language one is using.

```
bash -ex myscript.sh
```

The people who are working on the project can always edit the myscript.sh file in the subversion and at the same time they do not have the possibility to configure the project.